# Node.js MySQL module - throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors;

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, server-side

today I tried node.js mysql snippet from w3schools:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "roots", // WRONG USER
  password: ""
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  /*Create a database named "mydb":*/
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created");
  });
});
```

I wanted to learn how to handle mysql errors, because my app require mysql. But after I started app.js file this error showed up: [image]

Why can't I throw an error?

Comment: Well. You wanted to throw an error. You achieved it. What else do you need?

Comment: @LEQADA Why can't I catch it when I wrap con.connnect() to try-catch?

Comment: What you said to your application is to throw an error when there is any. And that is what your app is doing.

Comment: @LEQADA Shouldn't I be able to catch an exception?

Comment: Try to replace your first `if (err) throw err;` with this line `if (err) console.log("Oops... Something went wrong");`

Comment: The user you are using to connect doesn't have permissions to access your target database.

Comment: Did you manage to handle errors with my suggestion?

Comment: My doubt also, Why throwing the error is not caught in the catch scope?
When making `throws error` will be caught in `catch`, but here it is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wanted to learn how to handle mysql errors, because my app require
>   mysql.

[MySQLJS Error handling](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#error-handling)

To catch the errors you `throw`, try with the following snippet :

```
con.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[mysql error]",err);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

change you're database conn like this

```js
  var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'secret'

});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```