# I am getting an Error: ER_SP_UNDECLARED_VAR: Undeclared variable: NaN when trying AJAX request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

I am getting this error 
` throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_SP_UNDECLARED_VAR: Undeclared variable: NaN
`
when trying to do jQuery AJAX get request, and i don't know why.
I'm using node.js and MySQL for backend part, and jQuery for frontend part.
This is node.js:

```
Users.prototype.get_limited_data  = function(page_number, callback) {
    let blocksize = 12;
    let offset = (page_number - 1) * blocksize;
    var query = "select * from test_video_category limit ? offset ?";
    this.conn.query(query, [blocksize, offset], function(err,rows){
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(err,rows);
    })
};

router.get('/new-preview-page-data', function (req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        let page_number = req.query.page_number;
        let Users = new users(connection);
        Users.get_limited_data ( page_number,function (err, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('marketplace', { preview_data : rows});
        });
    });
});
```

And this is jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "new-preview-page-data",
    success: function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

And jade is used for templating.
This is the error

```
/home/nikola/Desktop/reevio/template_app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
    ^
```

Error: ER_SP_UNDECLARED_VAR: Undeclared variable: NaN

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

As its not clear what basically the error is, i would recommend you to first catch the error properly and then it will be know what's the problem is. To catch the error you can use this. Let me know if this help you out.

`con.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[mysql error]",err);
});`

There is a question which is ask already [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787211/node-js-mysql-module-throw-err-rethrow-non-mysql-errors).