# Response to Clear Input Textbox Validating Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm validating a form, and I'm sending the value of a textbox to be checked in the database if it's already there. If a match is found, I want a warning like change the placeholder of the textbox to say something like duplicate value found. Otherwise, just go to the next input.

On my HTML, I have:

```
<div class="inventry" id="myInventry">
<h2>Invoice entry:</h2>
    <form action="/inventry" method="post">
        <label for="invoicenumber"><b>Invoice Number:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="invoicenumber" id="invoicenumber" onchange="this.form.submit()" required>
```

On my server, I have:

```
app.post('/inventry', function(request, response) {
let invoicenumber = request.body.invoicenumber;

if(invoicenumber) {
    connection.query('SELECT Factura FROM tbl1facturas WHERE Factura = ?',[invoicenumber], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        if(results.length > 0) {
            response.set.body.invoicenumber("")
        }
        response.end();
    })
}
```

However, this is crashing the server, and I'm getting this error:

> ql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'invoicenumber')

I'm having no problem checking the code is working I know it works I'm only having trouble sending a response message to the form or the textbox itself.

I checked with this code and it's working:

```
app.post('/inventry', function(request, response) {
let invoicenumber = request.body.invoicenumber;

if(invoicenumber) {
    connection.query('SELECT Factura FROM tbl1facturas WHERE Factura = ?',[invoicenumber], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        if(results.length > 0) {
            response.send('Success!');
        } else {
            response.send('Fail!');
        }
        response.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using in your backend to handle the routing?

Comment: I'm using Express

Comment: Express requires additional module to extract incoming data into request.body, it's called `body-parser`. Do you have it installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js MySQL module - throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787211/node-js-mysql-module-throw-err-rethrow-non-mysql-errors)

Comment: @Leo yes I have it. What I'm needing is a way for it to send a response to clear my input textbox.

Comment: @Yilmaz no it doesn't help it's not a MySQL error instead I think my syntax for the response is wrong and I'm not able to change